# Maven Shade Plugin - How to include test classes and test resources?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, executable-jar, maven-shade-plugin

Im using maven shade plugin to generate an executable jar. But insead of having my `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` files get packaged, i would like to have the test folders `src/test/java` & `src/test/resources` get included instead.

I have already checked SO and other sources but I can't find a solution that works.

I tried accomplishing the same thing using other (one jar and assembly) plugins listed in [this](http://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) guide but still can't figure it out.

I also tried using the  tag in my shade pom config but i dont think I'm doing I'm using it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

My plugin entry:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.my.sample.package.test.Main</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [IncludeResourceTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#IncludeResourceTransformer) may help you.

Or alternatively, [this](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/manage-maven-directories/) page describes how to override the directories normally used by maven, including test resources. I'm thinking that in your pom.xml, you can include a build section, as shown in the examples, and include only testSourceDirectory and testResources, leaving out the others that you don't want included.

Comment: This looks promising. Will give it a try once I get the chance and accept your answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hope one of these works. I will try myself, too, as I am very curious and would like to verify..